# join and group the joins in array

Tags: mysql, sql

1. products
2. products_prop
3. specification

now i want to get the product and in cell i want to get array with all products_prop and the name from specification

if i do like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `product_prop`
ON products.id = product_prop.product_id
INNER JOIN `specification`
ON product_prop.specification_id = specification.id
GROUP BY products.name
```

what i need to do for get 1 row of product and the all product_prop in array with the name of specification?

Comment: You are probably looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: FWIW, to my way of thinking, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution, but for further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ok nice!
but now i get row like this 10,20,30,white,red 
and size,size,size,color,color

`SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(product_prop.value), GROUP_CONCAT(specification.name) FROM products INNER JOIN product_prop ON products.id = product_prop.product_id INNER JOIN specification ON product_prop.specification_id = specification.id`

how i can get size => 10,20,30 color => white,red